# Как создать вложенные partial классы?

Tags: c#, ооп

У меня есть класс Library, в котором есть несколько вложенных классов:

```
public class Library
{
class Book { /*Some code*/ }
class Author { /*Somecode*/ }
class Series { /*Somecode*/ }
class Topic { /*Somecode*/ }
}
```

Но очень много кода в одном файле, поэтому я решил вынести классы Book, Author, Series, Topic в отдельные файлы. Для этого я их сделал partial.

```
public class Library
    {
    partial class Book { }
    partial class Author { }
    partial class Series { }
    partial class Topic { }
    }

//Books.cs
partial class Book { /*Some code*/ }
...
```

Но что-то не работает, потому, что части partial класса не видят один одного.

Comment: что значит _части partial класса не видят один одного._? Приведи пример кода, который демонстрирует ошибку

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Я понял в чем проблема. Я в каждом отдельном классе писал просто так - partial class Book { /*Some code*/ }
А нужно было так - partial class Library { partial class Book { /*Some code*/ } }

Comment: @ValeraKvip, по твоей же ссылке: _The following example shows that **nested types can be partial**, even if the type they are nested within is **not partial** itself._

Comment: @Grundy  угу, не дочитал

Comment: @AndriyGoliyad, опишите решение как ответ, чтобы его легче было найти.

Comment: @AndriyGoliyad, интересный вопрос, спасибо. Но можно уточнить почему именно вложенные классы используете?

Comment: @Andriy Goliyad Я рад, что Вы решили проблему, но учитывайте - использование вложенных классов - плохой тон. еще хуже то что Вы делаете их частичными и определяете в нескольких местах..ю Используйте namespace Library и все. Частичные представления имеет смысл использовать только если Вы хотите поставлять dll без исходников другим разработчикам и хотите чтобы они могли расширить Ваш класс без наследования. В любых других случаях это только усложняет структуру приложения.

Comment: @4per В первую очередь мои вложенные классы(Author, Book, ...) используют приватные методы базового класса (Library). Плюс когда используешь какой-то вложенный класс, видно к какой штуки он принадлежит. То есть я пишу Library.Book book = ... и сразу понятно, что этот класс из самой моей библиотеки(Library). А то у меня есть еще классы по названию очень похожие на Book, но они предназначены для совсем других целей.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Частичный класс может быть вложенным в частичный или не частичный класс. В последнем случае охватывающий класс должен иметь одно определение. Например,

```
using System;

class Library
{
    public partial class Book
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Book
    {
        public string Author { get; set; }
    }

    public Book book;
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Library lib = new Library 
        { 
            book = new Library.Book { Title = "A good book", Author = "me" } 
        };

        Console.WriteLine( "\"{0}\" is written by {1}", 
                          lib.book.Title, lib.book.Author );
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль

```
"A good book" is written by me
```

Если же вы хотите, чтобы и охватывающий класс был определен в различных частях вместе с частичным вложенным классом, то вы его также должны объявить с модификатором `partial`.

Например,

```
using System;

partial class Library
{
    public partial class Book
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}

partial class Library
{
    public partial class Book
    {
        public string Author { get; set; }
    }
}

partial class Library
{
    public Book book;
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Library lib = new Library 
        { 
            book = new Library.Book { Title = "A good book", Author = "me" } 
        };

        Console.WriteLine( "\"{0}\" is written by {1}", 
                          lib.book.Title, lib.book.Author );
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет таким же, как показано выше.